# Reformatting an Acer E1-570

Tags: acer-aspire, factory-defaults

I’m trying to reformat an Acer E1-570 i5 from work. Customer returned the unit still logged in to their email, and by the looks of it, there were problems resetting it. Long story short, it wouldn’t sell, so I got it cheap.

My problem is, when I access the BIOS (<kbd>F2</kbd>) to perform a factory reset, the option is not selectable. It **is** an option, but it’s greyed out. Another interesting note, I went back in to take a picture for this question, and "set HDD password" was accessible. Previously, all I could do was set an admin password.

I have also found reference to a "reset wizard", accessed via holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> at startup, but nothing happens.

Do I have to trigger some sort of admin access to allow a BIOS factory reset, or should I be doing it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours waiting to speak to technical support at Acer, I had a solution.

Acer does not use the BIOS factory reset. Instead, you have to get to the Windows log-in screen, to perform a reset.

While holding <kbd>shift</kbd>, simply select the power icon, and hit "restart". The computer will load into the Windows Recovery Tool, and gives you the option to perform a full factory reset.